# Spring Batch CompositeItemWriter, execute batch at the end of traversal of each delegate Writer To improve performance

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In Spring batch my CompositeItemWriter is inserting records to multiple tables using multiple ItemWriters, But Currently Each of these ItemWriters are inserting in batch as shown below

```
public class Item{
  public List<WarningObject> warnings
  public List<ErrorObject> errors
  public Long Id;
  public String data1;
  public String data2;
  public String data3;
  // getters and setters

}
```

My Writer Configuration

```
<bean id="compositeItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
<property name="delegates">
<list>
    <ref bean="warningItemWriter"/>
    <ref bean="errorItemWriter"/>
    <ref bean="CustomJdbcItemWriter"/>
</list>
</property>
```

```
public class WarningItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Item>{

  @Autowire
   String sql;
  @AutoWire
   JdbcTemple jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowire
  ItemPreparedStatementSetter itemPreparedStatementSetter;

   @Override
   public void write(final List<? extends Item> items) throws Exception {
       for(Item item: items){

            jdbcTemplate.execute(sql,new PreparedStatementCallBack<int []>{
            @Override
                    public int[] doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                        for (WarningObject warning: item.getWarnings) {
                            itemPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(warning, ps);
                            ps.addBatch();
                        }
                        return ps.executeBatch();

             });
        }
   }

}
```

So This works fine, but this has not really become a batch insert of warnings

Currently it inserts all the Warnings of my one item in a batch. But I would ideally want to add warning of each item to preparedstatement and once all warnings of all items are added I want to call `ps.executeBatch()`

Can someone help me with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the outer loop to the inside of the anonymous class:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(sql, new PreparedStatementCallBack<int []> {
    @Override
    public int[] doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        for (Item item: items) {
            for (WarningObject warning: item.getWarnings) {
                itemPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(warning, ps);
                ps.addBatch();
             }
        }
        return ps.executeBatch();
    }
});
```